# Android ListView - retrieve visible bounds

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am trying to get the values of (any one of) the visible coordinates of a ListView. I have used a ScrollListener, but I'm not sure which property will give me these values. I eventually want to compute the direction of scroll using these values. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method.

```
listView.getLastVisiblePosition() in your onScroll listner
```

this will not give the coordinates but you will find easily the scrolling direction either Up or Down.

this will return an `int` value if it is increasing than your performing scroll down if ts decreasing then it means user is scrolling UP.

Comment: I know this one. :) I was hoping to perform a finer detection as the cells in my ListView are quite large and the position value doesn't change when a slow scroll is done.

Comment: I ended up using this one. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

`OnScrollListener` has a function you need to overwrite called `onScroll` which you can use to solve your problem. Here's a code snippet:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

     @Override
     public void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

          if (++firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount) {
               //Reached last element in list, Do Something...
          }
     }
}
```

You can use this to determine whether the user is scrolling up or down AND the coordinates. `firstVisibleItem` will give you the position/coordinates of the first visibile item in your list, `visibleItemCount` will tell you how many more elements are visible and `totalItemCount` speaks for itself.